# Disable kernel lockdown on 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, kernel, intel

I am trying to access a device connected through USB3 (an intel realsense depth camera), however I believe the kernel lockdown is blocking access to it.

```
dkms status
```

reads the proper camera, but when I try to check if data is being streamed with

```
dmesg -wT
```

I get a long output which culminates in this error message:

```
 Lockdown: systemd-udevd: unsigned module loading is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

How can I disable the kernel lockdown so that I can gain access to this device?

I have tried this as suggested by a few posts, but it has no effect:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo x > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use 3rd party unsigned kernel modules, you need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings.

Comment: Ok, I will try that tomorrow. I have a windows and ubuntu dual boot. I have tried disabling safe boot and booting to windows before, but it ends up giving me blue screens and boot not found errors, so I turned it back on. I have not tried straight to ubuntu yet. Is there a way to do this so that I don't have to turn Secure Boot on and off every time I want to switch? (This may be outside the purview of this forum if it is a windows issue, but I would love your help if you know anything)

Comment: Windows should boot with Secure Boot off.

Comment: It didn't work until I disabled bitlocker for some reason

Comment: I'm frustrated by these workaround "answers" disabling secure boot.  It feels like "I'm locked out of my home how do I get back in" - proposed solution "just throw a brick through the window".  Yes it works, but you lose something else in the process.

Better answers would include "how to self-sign your kernel modules" or "how to install 3rd party modules to be signed as part of dkms".

Comment: It is your choice, but my opinion is that Secure Boot is useless for security.